# Limit of composition function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Let $f,g:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g(x)$ is monotone increasing. Suppose $\lim_{x\to +\infty}g(f(x))=+\infty.$ Prove: $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty,\lim_{x\to +\infty}g(x)=+\infty.$

I know that, as $\lim_{x\to +\infty}g(f(x))=+\infty,\forall\ M>0 $ there exist $K>0$ such that $\forall\ x>K, |g(f(x))|>M.$
And, for $a\leq b, g(a)\leq g(b)$

But I do not know how to move forward from this point. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: If the function $f(x)$ _doesn't_ tend to infinity, then it either tends to a finite value, negative infinity, or has no limit when $x\rightarrow{+\infty}$. The second one is invalid, as $g(x)$ is only defined when $x>0$. If $f(x)$ converges to a particular finite value, so will $g(f(x))$, which contradicts the given statement. If $f$ has no limit, then $g(f(x))$ will not have one too. All this is because $g(x)$ is increasing monotonically

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: How do I show 'if f coverages to a finite value, so will g(f(x))"?

Comment: Added as answer

Comment: sorry my comment was not perfectly accurate. I have tried to rectify all the errors I made in the comment through my answer. If you still think that there may be some misconception on my side, please don't hesitate to ask. Actually I am new to this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a proof by contradiction:

If the function $f(x)$ doesn't tend to infinity, then it either tends to a finite value, negative infinity, or has no limit when $x\rightarrow+\infty$

The second one is invalid, as $g(x)$ is only defined when $x>0$.

If $f(x)$ converges to a particular finite real value $k$, then what the limit says is that $|f(x)-k|$ can be made smaller than any predetermined real $\epsilon>0$, simply by increasing the value of $x$. So, $f(x)=k+\alpha$ where $\alpha\rightarrow{0}$ when $x\rightarrow+\infty$. So $$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}g(f(x))=\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow{0}}g(k+\alpha)$$ Now if $k\leq0$, then the function $g$ is not defined. So, WLOG, $k>0$. If $g(x)$ is continuous in the region around $x=k$, then $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow{0}}g(k+\alpha)=g(k)$ (contradictory to given statement). If, however, it is discontinuous in that region, then, as the function is monotonically increasing, the limit must not exist (as every discontinuity is a jump discontinuity for monotonic functions, by [Froda's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuities_of_monotone_functions)). This contradicts the given statement.

If $f$ has no limit, then $g(f(x))$ will either have finite limit (if the value of $g$ is constant in the range in which the value of $f$ strays in when $x\rightarrow+\infty$) or will not have one, which also contradicts the given statement.

So we have shown via proof by contradiction that the proof statement must be true.